# Azure Function Logging to Function Monitor and App Insights

Tags: python, azure, logging, monitoring, python-logging

I'm trying to use my logger to send logs from my Azure Function to azure monitor and azure app insights but I'm currently only being able to log into app insights.

That is my code below:

```
import logging
import socket
from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler


#Fetching Hostname
logger = logging.getLogger(socket.gethostname())

class logger_config:
    def debug(debug, connection_string):
        logger = logging.getLogger(socket.gethostname())
        formatter = logging.Formatter(f'%(asctime)s : %(hostname)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s')
        azure_handler = AzureLogHandler(connection_string=connection_string)
        azure_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        if not logger.handlers:
            logger.addHandler(azure_handler)
        if debug == 'true':
            logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        if debug == 'false':
            logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

class log:
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    def INFO(x):
       logger.info(x)
    def DEBUG(x):
       logger.debug(x)
    def WARNING(x):
       logger.warning(x)
    def CRITICAL(x):
       logger.critical(x)
```

I tried everything I could, including trying to add two handlers into the logger, but no success.
The logger should be imported by the function on this way:

```
logger_config.debug(os.environ["debugMode"], os.environ["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"])
```

I appreciate the help of anyone who might know how to approach this situation.

Thanks!

Comment: azure app insights is a part of azure monitor, so what exactly do you expect to see regarding  azure monitor?

Comment: Hey... thanks for your reply. The logs are currently appearing on the azure app insight, if I query them in the portal, but they don't show on the function monitor console. What I expect to achieve is to see the logs in both the App Insights and the Monitor Console.

Comment: If you navigate to the function resource in the azure portal and select "Application Insights" from the left menu in the section "Settings" what does it show?

Comment: It shows my function app is connected to my app insights